# Ubuntu 16.04 custom application not launching after creating .desktop file

Tags: 16.04, .desktop

I hope I have a straight forward question that I am just not able to resolve because I am so inexperienced.

I am running Ubuntu 16.04 and want to use the astronomical image viewer sao-ds9. I tried to install it from the Ubuntu repositories but got package dependency errors. I then just downloaded the executable directly from the program webpage which works fine. I have set it up so that I can use it in the terminal. However, for convenience I also wanted to set .fits files to be opened by default with ds9. After some reading I created a new .desktop file for the application with the following content:

```
 [Desktop Entry]
Name=SAO-DS9
Comment=SAO-DS9
Exec=/home/user/ds9/ds9 %U
Icon=/home/user/ds9/station.png
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Categories=Viewer;Graphics;Qt;
```

I placed this file in `/usr/share/applications`. This worked to the point that I was able to select ds9 as default application for .fits files in the GUI. However, when I am no clicking a `.fits` file to open the icon pops up on the launcher and vanishes after a few seconds again without actually opening ds9 (which again works fine when started with the same fits file from the terminal).

I assume I somehow messed the .desktop file up, but I am not sure how. Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT:
Ok so I have a few additional detail to add, which to me make things even more confusing.

I have now reduced the ds9.desktop file to a pretty much bare bones version (I think):

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=SAO-DS9
Comment=SAO-DS9
Exec=/usr/local/bin/ds9 %f
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Categories=Graphic;FITS;
```

The behavior is remained the same until reboot of the system. After reboot all of a sudden it sort of worked. Meaning that now 2(!) icons popped up on the launcher and the application actually opened correctly (although with a short 1s delay compared to opening it from the terminal). One icon belonged to the now correctly opened application, the other was blinking for a few seconds and then vanished. While not ideal, i may have been able to live with this behavior. However, after the next reboot (without any change to the application or the .desktop file), it reverts back to the old behavior of just opening one icon which blinks and vanishes after a few seconds and not opening the application itself at all.

My system is a completely fresh install on a new dell laptop. I have run all Ubuntu updates. Anyone any idea how to fix this behavior? It is really disruptive of my work flow to not being able to open files by simply clicking on them :(

Comment: Are you sure `%U` (list of URLs) is appropriate? have you tried `%f`? FYI there seems to be some information about .desktop files for the application here: [Viewing multiextension FITS images](https://www.gnu.org/software/gnuastro/manual/html_node/Viewing-multiextension-FITS.html)

Comment: Indeed the %U option is probably wrong. I had tried %f first and got the same behavior, then saw someone suggesting %U so tried that. The link you show is very helpful indeed, thank you. Besides putting the -mecube option in (which I dont want), it would seem my .desktop file is overall similar. So in short now I am even more puzzled why its not working :(

Comment: For debugging, might be helpful to change `Terminal=false` to `Terminal=true` temporarily - and see if there are any error messages in the terminal

Comment: Good thought, thanks! What happens is that a terminal opens for a fraction of a second and then immediately closes. The icon in the launcher stays for a few seconds and then also vanishes without the actual program ever opening (as before, just wanted to describe the full behavior again.

Comment: Could it be the permissions of the .desktop file? Although it does seem to be accessed fine since the correct icon is loaded and behavior in fact changed when I set the terminal to true.

Comment: Hm sorry for the spam, but replying to my own question.....Permissions are identical for the ds9.desktop file and for other .desktop files. In fact I tried just for randoms sake to give it executable permission, which did not change anything.

Comment: Ok figured out how to keep the terminal open. I get an error message indeed, but I am not immediately understanding whats going on            `Error in startup script: couldn't read file "/zvfsmntpt/tcl8/8.5/msgcat-1.5.2.tm"`

Comment: When you set up the application so that it works in the terminal, were there extra environment variables or paths that you had to add?

Comment: No I could run it directly (it is just a self contained binary), either from the folder I unpacked it in, or from everywhere by copying it into /usr/local/bin